Integrate hadoop HDFS with Snowflake
I'm building personal project, but I got stuck.
Specifically, after writing spark jobs to process & transform data, I load data into hadoop HDFS. Then I want to connect hdfs to snowflake, then I can export data from hdfs to snowflake, but it doesn't seem to work.
After reading, I see that I need to use some cloud storage that some parties support like AWS, MCA, GCS, meaning that loading data from HDFS to cloud storage first, then export data from cloud to snowflake.
I want to know that is it a common way nowadays, and are there some other ways to solve this problem without using cloud storage?
Thank for all.

Hi - why are you loading data into HDFS and not straight into Snowflake? Do you really need the data in both platforms? If you want to move data from HDFS then, at a high level, there are at least 3 possible approaches 1) Use an ETL tool that can connect to both systems 2) Code your own solution using a language that can connect to both systems (python?) 3) Use Snowflake-native import processes which, as you mentioned in your question, would need the data on a Cloud storage system

Given that you're already using Apache Spark, you can just use the Snowflake Spark Connector to write your data directly into Snowflake.
That would be the shorter path rather than adding that hop of writing data to HDFS or a cloud storage service and then loading that data into Snowflake in a separate step.
